# How to get form name and input with javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, input, get

How I can get the value of input of form ONLY on submit? I have this..

```
<form id="addCommentForm<?PHP echo $PostID;?>" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" value="<?PHP echo $PostID;?>" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
  <textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

`$PostID` is number which in every form printed in the page is different and so all form names on the page are different. In HTML, it's looking like this:

First form printed:

```
<form id="addCommentForm3" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" value="3" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
  <textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

Second printed:

```
<form id="addCommentForm2" method="post" action="">
  <input type="hidden" value="2" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
  <textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

I am getting the `comentonpost` id value in javascript like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  var name_element = document.getElementById('comentonpost');
  var x = name_element.value;
});
```

I need this value so the following script will put the new comment over           `#addCommentContainer'+x`

**Here is the whole javascript:**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

var name_element = document.getElementById('comentonpost');
var x = name_element.value;

/* The following code is executed once the DOM is loaded */

/* This flag will prevent multiple comment submits: */
var working = false;

/* Listening for the submit event of the form: */
$('#addCommentForm'+x).submit(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    if(working) return false;

    working = true;
    $('#submit').val('Working..');
    $('span.error').remove();

    /* Sending the form fileds to submit.php: */
    $.post('comment.submit.php',$(this).serialize(),function(msg){

        working = false;
        $('#submit').val('Submit');


            /* 
            /   If the insert was successful, add the comment
            /   below the last one on the page with a slideDown effect
            /*/

            $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer'+x).slideDown();


    },'json');

});

   });
```

But in this way it's taking the value of the first form printed. How can I get the value of `comentonpost` only on the submitted form?

Answer (score 1):

As you're using jQuery, you can use the ["attribute starts with"](http://api.jquery.com/attribute-starts-with-selector/) selector to select the form, and the [`.serialize()`](http://api.jquery.com/serialize/) or [`.serializeArray()`](http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/) methods to get the entire form's data:

```
$('[id^="addCommentForm"]').on('submit', function (e) {
    var formData;
    //as string i.e. foo=bar&fizz=buzz
    formData = $(this).serialize();

    //as array i.e. [{name: 'foo', value: 'bar'}, {name: 'fizz', value: 'buzz'}]
    formData = $(this).serializeArray();
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

For the data of a single field within the form, you can simply select the field and call [`.val()`](http://api.jquery.com/val/):

```
fieldVal = $('#comentonpost').val();
```

That said, it'd be better to simply add a common class to all of the forms and select on that:

<sub>PHP:</sub>

```
<form class="add-comment-form" id="addCommentForm<?PHP echo $PostID;?>" method="post" action="">
```

<sub>JS:</sub>

```
$('.add-comment-form').on('submit'...
```

---

*Be careful with spelling*, you've used `addCommentform` for the form, but `comentonpost` for the field.

Comment: Here is the whole javascript code - http://jsfiddle.net/UVkuE/
I need the <code>comentonpost</code> value because this script need the form name so the script can print the new comment. Tell me how i can get this input value in this script please. I dont get it...

Answer (score 0):

Add `onsubmit` property to the form like this:

```
<form id="addCommentForm<?php echo $PostID;?>" method="post" action="" onsubmit="doSomething(this, event)">
    <input type="hidden" value="<?php echo $PostID;?>" name="comentonpost" id="comentonpost"/>
    <textarea class="commentinput" name="body" id="body" cols="20" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" />
</form>
```

javascript:

```
var working = false;

function doSomething(elm, e) {
    var form    = elm,
        x       = form.comentonpost.value,
        submit  = form.submit;

    e.preventDefault();
    if (working) return false;
    working = true;
    submit.value = 'working..';
    $('span.error').remove();

    $.post('comment.submit.php', $(form).serialize(), function (msg) {
        working = false;
        submit.value = 'submit';
        $(msg.html).hide().insertBefore('#addCommentContainer' + x).slideDown();
    }, 'json');

}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arcm111/6Nv5u/)

Comment: Thanks and how i can get this value in javascript? I want to make var x to be equal to commentpost input.

Comment: `this.commentonpost.value` will get the value of the `commentonpost` input of the submitted form only, you can then do whatever you want with it.

Comment: `onsubmit="doSomething(<?PHP echo $PostID;?>)"` if you inline code you could as well just expand that php variable to give the JS-Function a constant.

Answer (score 0):

First off let me point out that you have invalid XML there. The `id` attribute needs to be unique. However your `comentonpost` inputs all have the same `id`. Since you seem to intend to have a multiple of these forms on your page the **`id`s are ambiguous**. Instead of `id` you should use `class`. (The same goes for your ids `body` and `submit`.)

Based on this fix here is a jQuery function doing what you want:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(eventObject){        
        var commentOnPost = $(this).find(".comentonpost");
        var x = $(commentOnPost[0]).val();
        alert(x); // for debuggin prompts the found value
        return false; // this will prevent form submit - you might have to remove it
    });
});
```

[DEMO HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/qzG5u/6/)

Comment: I don't know where but there is some mistake in this DEMO, when i press submit it's doing nothing but printing error. Here is the whole JAVASCRIPT - http://jsfiddle.net/UVkuE/ . I need this input so this scirpt will print the new comment over "#addCommentContainer'+x"

Comment: Might be an old link reload this page and try again. Else it is an alert prompt meant for illustration. `alert(x)` shows a pop-up window telling you the `value` of the currently submitted form's `comentonpost`-element.

Comment: Weird must be a browser compatibility issue. Works for me in FF21.

Comment: Can you please check this http://jsfiddle.net/UVkuE/ and tell me what i have to change in this script to make it working like it should? Thanks in advance!

Comment: @ViolinaMilanova [try this](http://jsfiddle.net/S3KBx/2/) Note that if you are using IE these jsFiddles will probably not function for you because of running in the jsFiddle sandbox, not because the scripts are broken ([known bug](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/13936)). Give this [jsbin one](http://jsbin.com/atalir/1/edit) a try instead.